# STR_PAD_RIGHT works but not STR_PAD_LEFT in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to PAD zeros to the left in order to display in a CSV. But it does not work. I tried  STR_PAD_RIGHT (for testing Purpose) which works.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        if (ctype_digit(($row["$i"]))) {
            $num = intval($row["$i"]);
            $num1 = str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $out_csv .= '"' . $num1 . '",';
        } else {
            $out_csv .= '"' . $row["$i"] . '",';
        }
    }
    $out_csv .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: if $row["$i"]  returns me a number I would want to prepend it with Zeros. Eg., if $row["$i"] returns me 1 I want the $num1 to be 0001 but I get only 1 as a result

Comment: Yes. If I do STR_PAD_RIGHT I get result as 1000

Comment: As a side note you can try to force it to resolve to string by ``$num1 = ''.str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`` and test it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the resulting CSV with a spreadsheet (excel, libreOffice...), it will delete the zeros. Check with a simple notepad if the zeros are there or not. If yes, it's the spreadsheet, if you want to display them, you have to put another character first (like a dot for example). If no, your values are they up to 4 chars ? because str_pad only fill up to the 2nd parameter (here, 4). So if your value is 1234, it won't fill with zeros. If your value is 123, it should display 0123.

Comment: Yes... That was the problem.. Did not think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideone snippet [STR_PAD_LEFT snippet](https://ideone.com/WvWFOj) shows that it works fine.

```
$num = 1;
$num1 = ''.str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $num1;
```